# just started apache .htaccess rewrite to lighttpd conversion

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

Below is my .htaccess file from apache. I'm getting a 404 not found error on my subdirectories, and I am certain it has to do with my rewrite.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* file.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Here is my lighttpd.conf rewrite

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "www.example.com" {
url.rewrite           = ( "^(.*)$" => "$1.php" )
}

server.follow-symlink = "enable"
```

I know the "$1.php" isn't the right answer. It sort-of works, but I wouldn't consider it functional. It's sole purpose here is to help put together what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

For

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

see https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRedirect

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
    url.redirect = ( "^(.*)$" => "http://www.example.com$1" )
}
```

For

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* file.php [L,QSA]
```

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/6459

For !-f and !-d See `url.rewrite-if-not-file` in https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite

For QSA, match the query string using a lighttpd condition block and then substitute with %1, e.g.

```
$HTTP["querystring"] =~ "(.*)" {
  url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "..." => "...&%1" )
} else {
  url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "..." => "..." )
}
```

Comment: In modern lighttpd, you can get QSA-behavior in rewrites using `url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "..." => "...${qsa}" )`